# combining object with Meta and django models.Model

Tags: python, django

some newbie question here, I have a model like so:

```
from django.db import models

class SomeCommons(object):
   # some fields here
   # ...
   class Meta:
      abstract=True

class SomeDjangoModels(SomeCommons,models.Model):
   pass
```

is it the same as the following model :

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModels(models.Model):
   # some fields here
   # ...
   class Meta:
      abstract=True
```

What I know that when doing like so `SomeDjangoModels(SomeCommons,models.Model)` the attribute from `SomeCommons` will be available in `SomeDjangoModels`, but the question is **if the `SomeCommons` contains django `Meta` class will the `Meta` class also available in `SomeDjangoModels`? if it is, is there a way to prove it (the Meta class does exists)?**

thanx

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: the meta class is still exist or not in combined object ? and a way to know it is still exists ?

Comment: every model class has meta class, check here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L61

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meta classes are inherited...

> [Meta inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance)
>
> When an abstract base class is created, Django makes any Meta inner class you declared in the base class available as an attribute. If a child class does not declare its own Meta class, it will inherit the parent’s Meta. If the child wants to extend the parent’s Meta class, it can subclass it.

But in your case it does nothing as absrtact is set to False on the inheriting child class.

> **Django does make one adjustment to the Meta class of an abstract base class: before installing the Meta attribute, it sets `abstract=False`.**

Asa result `SomeModels` will be abstract, but `SomeDjangoModels` will not.

Answer (score -1):

No, those two definitions are not quite the same.

By default, [a subclass will inherit its parent's `Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance), but it will *not* inherit the `abstract=True` property (as the common use case is that subclasses will not be abstract).

If you do wish to inherit that, you must explicitly override the meta class, as shown in the documentation.  (It appears from the question that you do wish `SomeDjangoModels` to also be abstract, but it's not entirely clear.)

If you do want a concrete (cf meta) subclass, then for all practical purposes the definitions are identical.